# Agregar a Transifex nuevo aviso de uso de cookies (Mayo 2018)

Tags: bug, agregar-a-transifex, legal

En [Brace yourselves: The GDPR is coming!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310321/289691) (Meta SE) se anunciaron cambios. Pues entre estos está un aviso de uso de cookies el cual no está en Transifex.

Texto plano

> This site uses cookies to deliver our services and to show you relevant ads and job listings. By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service. Your use of Stack Overflow’s Products and Services, including the Stack Exchange Network, is subject to these policies and terms.

HTML

```html
<p class="mb0 lh-lg">
  This site uses cookies to deliver our services and to show you relevant ads and job listings. By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our
  <a class="s-link s-link__inherit td-underline fc-white" target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy">Cookie Policy</a>,
  <a class="s-link s-link__inherit td-underline fc-white" target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>, and our
  <a class="s-link s-link__inherit td-underline fc-white" target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public">Terms of Service</a>. Your use of Stack Overflow’s Products and Services, including the Stack Exchange Network, is
  subject to these policies and terms.
</p>
```

Comment: Mantengamos vivo esto.. salvo que JuanM pueda hacer algo, vamos a tener que esperar que gerv vuelva de sus vacaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuestras políticas legales solamente están escritas en inglés y dado que el aviso trata sobre esto, el lenguaje que se usará únicamente será el inglés.  No se va a traducir esto, lo acabo de confirmar con nuestro equipo legal.

Comment: Es comprensible y muy bueno tener esto aclarado. Gracias.

Comment: Caramba, me parece sorprendente. Resulta poco coherente con la voluntad de tener un sitio plenamente en español.

Comment: @fedorqui lo se...la onda legal esta fuera de mis manos.